# issue with sqlite3 gem while using ruby, sinatra & Rake

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I have the sqlite3 gem in my Gemfile.  Running 'bundle install' works without errors.  When running a dababase migration using Rake:

```
rake db:create_migration NAME=create_messages
```

I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

I even tried specifying sqlite3 with 1.3.3 and then with 1.3.4 versions in the Gemfile but that did not resolve the issue.  Ruby version is 1.9.3

Following is from my environments.rb file:

```
configure :development do
 set :database, 'sqlite:///dev.db'
 set :show_exceptions, true
end
```

Following is from Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
#ruby "1.9.3"

gem "sinatra"
gem "activerecord"
gem "sinatra-activerecord"
gem 'sinatra-flash'
gem 'sinatra-redirect-with-flash'

group :development do
 gem 'sqlite3-ruby'
 gem "tux"
end
```

I have also tried sqlite3 in place of sqlite3-ruby but that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Show your database.config. I think you're using `sqlite` adapter instead of `sqlite3`.
Oh, show your "set :database" too

Comment: @IgorPavlov - I tried updating my post - any thoughts? thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
set :database, 'sqlite3:///dev.db'
```

Comment: I tried that earlier - I don't think it worked.  I'm updating ruby version and everything else now

Answer (score 0):

This was resoved after upgrading to ruby v2.2.1 and updating all the gems again.  I installed v2.2.1 via RVM.